# Someone suggested i use Jquery to validate my Form But its not working, how do i fix?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, validation

```
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"     type="text/javascript"></script>
<script     src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.14.0/jquery.validate.js">            </script>
<script     src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.14.0/jquery.validate.min.jsSS">    </script>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<script>
$function() {
$("#Subscribe").validate({
    rules: {
        Name: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 2,
            maxlength: 15,
            },
        Email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
            },
        Dob: {
            required: true,
            number: true
            },
            </script>
</head>

<body>
<form id="Subscribe" method="POST" action="subscribe.php">
<p><span>Enter Name: </span><input id="Name" type="text" name="Name"     size="20"></p>
<p><span>Enter Email: </span><input id="Email" type="text" name="Email"     size="20"></p>
<p> Enter DOB: <input id="Dob" type="text" name="Dob" size="20"></p>
<p ><span><input type="submit" value="Save Data" name="Submit"></span></p>
</form>
</body>
```

And the PHP which leads to another page once true

```
$location = "subscribe.1.homepage.html";
header( "Location: $location" );
```

I need to code to have validation on the email, dob and name and I cant seem to get it working. I believe i've done it all correctly but arnt too sure. i only started looking into it last night

Comment: to add to the answers you only need either the `jquery.validate.min.js` or `jquery.validate.js` not both. Currently you have a typo there as well(jquery.validate.min.jsSS) and for the `DoB` field , use `date:true` instead of `number:true`

Comment: What do you mean by 'not working'? Specifics are helpful. And you can use client side validation as a way to improve the UI and give visual feedback to the user but you shouldn't rely on it to safety check the user input... I can remove your JS from the browser dev tools. Always have a server side validation as well.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#Subscribe").validate({

rules: {

    Name: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 2,
        maxlength: 15
        },

    Email: {
        required: true,
        email: true
        },

    Dob: {
        required: true,
        number: true
        }
    }});

});
```

Comment: how would adding the top part of the code help? The $doc and $("Sub sections? thanks for the () and {} issues though

Answer (score 1):

your script terminates a little prematurely

```
$(function() { // you missed the first ( on this line
    $("#Subscribe").validate({
        rules: {
            Name: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 2,
                maxlength: 15,
            },
            Email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            Dob: {
                required: true,
                number: true
            }, // you stopped here!!
```

need the following at least

```
        }
    })
});
```